# DateTime ParseExact is giving different date format result in different Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

DateTime.ParseExact does not give me the exact result as expected.

Following is the line of Code which behaves differently in different projects :

```
 var dateSting = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString("dd-M-yyyy");
 var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateSting, "dd-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

This **date** object is tightly bound to the UI using MVC. So i cant convert the date to String and use it on UI. UI expects DateTime type only. 
In the sample project i created this gives date result in the format : **dd-M-yyyy** 
But in the Project it gives result in the format : **dd/m/yyyy**. I have commented the globalization tag from the Web.Config file as well.

Any pointers why this is happening. ?

Comment: Add `.ToString("dd-M-yyyy")` at end of second line,

Comment: @Mairaj : But that will convert the date to a string. I need a DateTime Object only

Comment: @Mairaj : I am using MVC. UI is tightly bound to the object So i need to use DateTime only.

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format, so it's unclear what you're trying to achieve, or why you're formatting a string only to parse it again.

Comment: @JonSkeet : I need to show the particular date format on UI. Its MVC View and is tightly bound to the object and the property what i am looking at is DateTime type. Twitter Bootstrap is used and TwitterBootstrapDateTime picker is used.

Comment: So you need to research how to perform formatting within MVC. The `DateTime` value is not the problem: the formatting is. (Look at `[DisplayFormat]` for example...)

Comment: @JonSkeet : UI formatting when date is selected from calendar is done and changes are made. But the default date value is not coming in the correct format. Thats need to be send from ServerSide. Thats why i am parsing the DateTime to correct format- DateTime is not giving me the correct format

Comment: I give up. I've explained this to you as many times as I can: **a `DateTime` value doesn't have a format**. You need to specify a format when you parse a string, and specify a format when you format it *to* a string, and that's all. Please read that again and again until you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

```
var dateSting = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString("dd-M-yyyy");
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateSting, "dd-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Can you provide us with an example?

Comment: In my sample the date i get is in the format : dd-M-yyyy but in the project it gives result as dd/M/yyyy although the same code is used

Comment: I'm asking what are the values that you get? I tried with current date (9. feb. 2017) and it works as it's supposed to.

Comment: With sample value received is 09-Feb-2017 but in the project with same code value received is 09/02/2017

Comment: dateSting in your case should be "09-2-2018". Is it? And when you parse it, you shoud get "9. Feb. 2018". Do you?

Comment: When dateSting is parsed, it should give : 09-Feb-2018

Comment: No, DateTime.ParseExact returns a DateTime object - and DateTime doesn't have any format, it's just an object.

Comment: The returned DateTime object can have date represented in different formats like : 09/02/2018 hh:mm:ssss , 09-Feb-2018 , 02/09/2018.

Comment: No, the returned `DateTime` value doesn't have a format (as you have been informed many times now). When you convert it to a string, it will use the current thread's current culture's default format if you don't specify a culture/format.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` since `en-US` might be overriding the desired format.

Comment: Have done that. But still not giving desired result.  
In my sample the date i get is in the format : dd-M-yyyy but in the project it gives result as dd/M/yyyy although the same code is used

Comment: On this site : http://rextester.com/                                                           try this code :   var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-M-yyyy"), "dd-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    
           Console.WriteLine("{0}",date);

Comment: @SunilA - It makes **absolutely no sense** to convert a `DateTime` to string and then parse it back to `DateTime`.  A `DateTime`  **has no format**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in last line.

```
var dateSting = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString("dd-M-yyyy");
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateSting, "dd-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
string result = date.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //Adding this code
```